# Django - link to url from different apps redirecting to the same links

Tags: python, django

I have three apps in the project which have different templates with different URLs but one I go the someone app template page then the links on this page are showing to other app URL whereas I have different apps with different URLs name

When I changed the name of templates files of every app then working fine.

Please give me a solution what is the problem getting with the same name file in a different app.
Thanks

Admin App

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login', views.login, name='admin_login'),
    path('register', views.register, name='admin_register'),
    path('logout', views.logout, name='admin_logout'),
    path('dashboard', views.dashboard, name='admin_dashboard')
]
templates
----pages
------login.html
------register.html
```

Customer App

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login', views.login, name='customer_login'),
    path('register', views.register, name='customer_register'),
    path('logout', views.logout, name='customer_logout'),
    path('dashboard', views.dashboard, name='customer_dashboard')
]
templates
----pages
------login.html
------register.html
```

When I changed to

```
templates
----pages
------customer_login.html
------customer_register.html
```

Then working but I can not find an issue why is giving this type of error whereas I have a different app with different vies, templates, URLs, and pathname where I'm redirecting.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the order Django scans the url patterns to find a match and trigger the matched view.

If you really want to keep this design you will have to do it like so:

```
adminapp/templates
             -----adminapp    # add this
                --------pages
                   ---------login.html
etc.
```

so within your template dirs of each app add another dir level called after the app's name. That way you ensure that Django will pick the correct template.